# How to backup Startup Applications?

Tags: backup, restore, startup-applications

I have some programs I have added to the Startup-Applications list and they all work fine at start up.

I'd like to back up those entries but I cannot find them. I searched online and found that /etc/xdg/autostart contains a lot of Ubuntu stuff, but not the ones I added.

What Folder data do I have to backup such that a restore will reinstate **my added** Startup Applications.

Thanks

Comment: in lubuntu they are found in /home/user/.config/autostart

Comment: @ptetteh227, please convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @ptetteh227: Thanks. That is already included in the backup so not sure what went wrong after the Restore as I had to add it manually again. I am using BackinTime so no idea why StartUp Applications didn't find it. Thanks again anyway. The app might not have been installed at that point as I can't remember the sequence I did things in, so thanks for that tip too.

Comment: +1 I will check my daily backup for this too. Perhaps your restore wouldn't go over newer file of a fresh installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you added the programs to autostart yourself then they would be located in **`/home/<user>/.config/autostart`** as *`.desktop`* files. you can copy all the files for your backup. To restore you can return them to that same location. For them to work, the application they are pointing to must be installed.

If you use lubuntu another location where autostart program/commands can be found is inside the file  **`/home/<user>/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart`**.

Comment: +1 I just added `/home/<user>/.config/autostart` to my daily gmail.com backup.